# batch on windows not finishing mysql job

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a .sql file 25 sql statements, that runs ok when all statements are copypasted into mysql client It takes app 20 mins to finish and no warnings are displayed. However, if I call this file through batch file on windows (I would like to add this to task scheduler) - - the job does not get finished. I can see which statement is the problem - however - no warnings get displayed - I can only see in (show processes), that mysql process end and no subsequent commands from the file get executed - this happens somewhere in the middle on my initial sql file. Again - the statement get executed ok when copypasted into mysql console. If anyone has any idea - would appreciate a lot..

```
c:
cd\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.7\bin
mysql --show-warnings -h12.24.56.78 -u user -ppass --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 < "C:\SVN\dis\777e\777a_777e\777a_ua_into_777e.sql" >> "C:\Users\user1\db_transfers\777a_ua\777a_ua_into_777e_warnings.log" 2>&1
```

Comment: Show your batch code, there could be problem with STDERR redirection.

Comment: I do not see any problems, note that `2>&1` overwrite, not append....

Comment: @user2956477, `2>&1` does not control whether a file is overwritten or appended, it only redirects handle `2` (_STDERR_) to where handle `1` (_SDOUT_) currently points to; handle `1` is redirected to the log file in append mode (`>>`, same as `1>>`); so all in all, any new data at both streams _STDOUT_ and _STDERR_ are finally appended to the log file...

Comment: ok, I've tried without warning log - - and the same happened. i can see in mysql that the process is gone and the execution is not complete..

Comment: Prepend 'echo' command before the last line of your script and watch if batch file somehow change it oposit to original line. This could be issue..